# Regex to match instances of X unless they're within comments

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have this regex that matches an 'if' statement if it follows a comment:

```
 (?:(\/\*[\w\s\']*)|(\/\/[\w\s\']*))if
```

What I need is to find all instances of 'if' as long as they don't match the regex above, so if the 'if' statement is within comments ignore it, otherwise match it. Is this possible with Regex alone? This feels like its very close.

Comment: Your question makes sense, I dunno why negative votes. anyway, you are talking about quoted comments or code comments?

Comment: because your regex seem to target code comments with `\/\*` and `\/\/` but when trying it will work on quoted comments lol

Comment: For code comments it is not fully doable in one regex: you have to discard the case where `//` or `/* */` is inside quotes and also handle the nested quotes and backslashed quotes.

You can do in multiple steps with first parsing a flag variable storing the state of opening and closing quotes first.

and then if your flag says comment currently closed then you match the if.

Not sure it is fully doable in JS.

Answer (score 0):

How about first cleaning the code from comments using REGEX and then make a second run on the clean code?

I did it in SQL using REGEXP_REPLACE with a PCRE dialect but I'm sure you'll get the hang of it

[SQL/Regex Challenge/Puzzle: How to remove comments from SQL code (by using SQL query)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911386/sql-regex-challenge-puzzle-how-to-remove-comments-from-sql-code-by-using-sql-q)

P.s.
You might also want to remove string using the same concept.