# Count Total PL/SQL Code Lines without Comments

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I was tasked to modify a Package and while doing so, i commented out the lines to be modified to retain versioning and commented it with Version Numbers.

Now that i'm done modifying the Package, i want to compare the total number of code lines of the Original the Modified Scripts without the line comments.

Is there any way this feature is available in SQL Developer / Notepad ++ / PL/SQL Developer or any other freeware / online tool?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you have both versions defined in the DB / saved in a table?

Comment: Hi @DuduMarkovitz, yes, i compiled both Scripts in TEST and just appended the name with "_v1" for the new package. I'm trying to query DBA_SOURCES but i can't get the right filtering condition since there are multiple ways the codes were commented (multi-line, single-line, etc.)

Comment: If you're commenting out code for versioning you're doing it horribly wrong.  This is what version control software is for.  Dead code should be deleted or you'll end up with a horrible mess very quickly.

Comment: Hi @JonHeller, unfortunately, the current organization i'm in does not have a version control software. :( so i'm left to do it the old way.

Comment: I'm not sure that is "the old way". Every system I have worked on since I think 1991 has used source control, originally `sccs` which was included free in Unix. Can't you at least save the old version in a numbered text file somewhere secure?

Comment: Hi @WilliamRobertson, yes, i've saved it on one of my local drives and in the test server's directories as well. I'll bring it up if we can just remove the comments and go ahead with the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on one of my posts -
[SQL/Regex Challenge/Puzzle: How to remove comments from SQL code (by using SQL query)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911386/sql-regex-challenge-puzzle-how-to-remove-comments-from-sql-code-by-using-sql-q)

---

```
create or replace package dmarkovitz.old_code as
1
2       2
3
/* yada yada yada */
4
5  '-- not a comment '
6
-- bla bla bla
7
8  "/* also not a comment"
9
10 'and again, not a comment */'
end;
/
```

---

```
create or replace package dmarkovitz.new_code as
1
2  /* bla bla bla */     2
-- 3
/* yada yada yada */
4
5  '-- not a comment ' 
/*6
-- bla bla bla
7
8  "/* also not a comment"
9 */
10 'and again, not a comment */'
end;
```

---

```
select      owner
           ,object_name
           ,object_type
           ,ddl
           ,uncommented_ddl
           ,regexp_count (uncommented_ddl,chr(10))  as lines

from       (select      owner
                       ,object_name
                       ,object_type
                       ,ddl
                       ,regexp_replace (ddl,'(''.*?''|".*?")|/\s*\*.*?\*/\s*|\s*--.*?(?=$|\z)','\1',1,0,'mn') as uncommented_ddl

            from       (select      owner
                                   ,object_name
                                   ,object_type
                                   ,dbms_metadata.get_ddl (object_type,object_name,owner)   as ddl

                        from        all_objects

                        where       owner       = 'DMARKOVITZ'
                                and object_name in ('OLD_CODE','NEW_CODE')
                                and object_type = 'PACKAGE'
                        )
            )   
;
```

---

```
OWNER         OBJECT_NAME    OBJECT_TYPE    DDL     UNCOMMENTED_DDL    LINES
----------    -----------    -----------    ----    ---------------    -----
DMARKOVITZ    NEW_CODE       PACKAGE        CLOB    CLOB               8
DMARKOVITZ    OLD_CODE       PACKAGE        CLOB    CLOB               13
```

---

#### OLD_CODE uncommented_ddl

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "DMARKOVITZ"."OLD_CODE" as
1
2       2
3
4
5  '-- not a comment '
6
7
8  "/* also not a comment"
9
10 'and again, not a comment */'
end;
```

#### NEW_CODE uncommented_ddl

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "DMARKOVITZ"."NEW_CODE" as
1
2  2
4
5  '-- not a comment ' 
10 'and again, not a comment */'
end;
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with the alternative quoting syntax, such as:  `string := q'[  '  ]';`

Comment: @MigsIsip, have you checked this solution?

Comment: hi @DuduMarkovitz, i'll check this out in a bit. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have backup package and clone package.then You cna use "Beyond Compare" tool.it is very useful to comapre the text files. you can open both backup package and clone package then easily to find the changes in your code.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Source Control Explorer to compare versions either on the server or on the file system.  I recommend it over many other compare tools.  Attached is an example image.[image]