# Remove comments from SQL/PLSQL blocks

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I was looking for a way to remove comments from SQL/PLSQL blocks.
It should follow the following criteria:

1. Single line comments (--) should be removed.
2. Multi line comments (/**/) should be removed.
3. But most importantly if these comments come inside strings (single or double quotes) they should be ignored.

I have tried several regexes but non of then are able to capture what I need.
like for example:

1. `--(?!.*(['""])[^'""]*\1)[^'\n\r]*`  -> for single line comments
2. `(''.*?''|".*?")|/\*.*?\*/|--.*?(?=$|\Z)`  -> for all cases

The second regex I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911386/sql-regex-challenge-puzzle-how-to-remove-comments-from-sql-code-by-using-sql-q), this does not for all the cases.

Can someone please provide a sample using the regex in c# regex engine.

**PS : should I be proceeding with a Regex matching approach?**

Comment: No idea. However, aren't those comments there *for purpose*?

Comment: Im working on a SQL parser, in which I need to remove them for further processing.

Comment: `('[^']*')*.*(-{2}.*)` The last group captures the inline comments (only checking for single quotes but should be easy to extend). Also does not take care of escaped quotes.

Comment: @soupy-norman can you verify if this regex works for `'-- comment 2'` case. Ideally it should not match with this string as its inside single quotes.

Comment: Can we assume the quoted strings will not contain newlines? Can multi-line comments be nested?

Comment: I think if I had a parser I would expect it to handle comments. If it doesn't, I would get a new parser. Comments are your friend, they need to be respected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that multi-line comments may not be nested, you can proceed in four steps.

First, replace any newlines in a quoted (single or double) string with a special character pattern that won't be found in the input. From what I can tell, PL/SQL or SQL*Plus support no special escape characters so I chose `\!` as the replacement.

```
var deNLquoted = Regex.Replace(src, @"('[^']*'|""[^""]*"")", m => m.Value.Replace("\n", @"\!"));
```

Then, match from the beginning of the line including any quoted strings, and then match a single-line comment marker to the end of the line. Replace with the match without the single-line comment:

```
var deSingleLineComment = Regex.Replace(deNLquoted, @"^((?:'[^'\n]*'|""[^""\n]*""|[^'""]+?)*?)--.*$", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline|RegexOptions.NonBacktracking);
```

Then, match from the beginning of the line including any quoted strings, and then match a multi-line comment. Replace with the match without the multi-line comment:

```
var deMultilineComment = Regex.Replace(deSingleLineComment, @"((?:'[^']*'|""[^""]*""|[^'""\n]+?)*?)/\*([^*]|\*[^/])*?\*/", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline|RegexOptions.NonBacktracking);
```

Finally remove any blank lines left over from deleting whole comment lines and then convert the newline markers in the de-commented string back to newlines.

```
var ans = deMultilineComment.Replace("\n\n", "\n").Replace(@"\!", "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the quotes can have a new line in it.

Comment: @XXDIL Out of curiosity, what type of SQL are you supporting that allows newlines? E.g. for T-SQL, you could remove any `\\\n` before processing comments.

Comment: Its Oracle SQL, the script will come in as a text file with multiple commands in one file. Each command need not be in a single line.

Comment: @XXDIL The code handles newlines in commands fine - it just assume there will be no newlines between quotes - is it possible for a quoted string to be split across multiple lines?

Comment: yes exactly, one quoted string can be in multiple lines. Eg str = `select 'multi\nline\nstring' from dual;`

Comment: @XXDIL I modified my answer to handle multiline quoted strings.

Comment: For some reason the multiLine comment removal step is going into an infinite loop.

Comment: @XXDIL Can you provide a sample query?

Comment: ```String src = @"--this is a test\n
saff like '--this comment should stay' --this should be removed\n
""-- dont remove 1""  ""sdsads \n
sadas f -- dont remove 2"" --remove\n
-- remove this asap\n
""ertret ret "" -- remove this too \n
'efsdf dsf df -- dont remove 3 '\n
'fsfsdf' -- remove this too\n
'fsdfsdf\n
dfsf -- dont remove 4 '";```

Comment: also there is one more issue with your approach, say the user decides to run this querry `select 'SQL \! SQL' from dual;` this will add a new line in place of the \!. Which will make the query wrong.

Comment: @XXDIL That's why I said "with a special character pattern that won't be found in the input"; your requirements don't seem to match PL/SQL or SQL*PLUS so I'm not sure what that pattern might be.

Comment: @XXDIL I modified the code to add `RegexOptions.NonBacktracking` to the multiline removal - it shouldn't need to backtrack, but is doing exponential attempts when it tries.

Comment: PS Since those SQLs seem to expect visible characters in quoted strings, a non-visible pattern like `"\v!"` could also be used.